# lists:foreach returns ok in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have just started in Erlang and find it difficult to understand.
I want to split a list into a string, run `string:titlecase` on it, and join it into a string.

```
namecase(Text) ->
    TextArray = string:split(Text, " ", all),
    lists:join(" ", lists:foreach(fun(Element) -> string:titlecase(Element) end, TextArray)).
```

but it fails with the error message `escript: exception error: no function clause matching lists:join(" ",ok) (lists.erl, line 1449)` because it returns `ok`,
Why does it return ok?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`lists:foreach` doesn't return the value that the function passed to it returns. It's meant to be used with functions that only cause side effects (e.g. printing). You're looking for `lists:map`.

```
1> Text = "foo bar baz".
"foo bar baz"
2> TextArray = string:split(Text, " ", all).
["foo","bar","baz"]
3> lists:join(" ", lists:map(fun(Element) -> string:titlecase(Element) end, TextArray)).
["Foo"," ","Bar"," ","Baz"]
```

And also, the anonymous function can be made shorter using `fun module:name/arity` syntax:

```
4> lists:join(" ", lists:map(fun string:titlecase/1, TextArray)).
["Foo"," ","Bar"," ","Baz"]
```

Comment: Perhaps add one more refining step (after replacing the fun), replacing `lists:map` with a list comprehension? It might be advanced, but it is also idiomatic.